# Which one should be chosen: "every - either"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

### In my High school final exam.

> ... sport is fantastic, so I can't have a favorite one.

1. Every
2. Either

Comment: what do you think the right answer is and why?

Comment: I think it is either, according to the rest if the sentence, we should deal with each sport alone, "Each" is right in the same context.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you gave us the context.

Comment: It depends entirely on context—which isn't given. How many sports is the person talking about? Without that information, there can be no one-or-the-other answer. If this were an actual test question, I would tear up the test and throw it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for constructs like these "either" implies only 2 options, while "every" implies at least 3 options. Without any other context, since there are more than three sports, **"every" is correct to me**.

Putting "each" in the blank creates a sentence with the same logical meaning as putting  "every" in the blank. However it implies "each in their own specific way", versus "every" implies that all sports share a similar sportsy-ness that you like and that is why you can't have a favorite.

Finally, using "each" also implies that there is a finite number of sports that the person is considering, where as using "every" does not.

---

That being said, using "either sport is" could also work if someone was asked to pick a favorite between two sports. However "both sports are" would be more common to use.